# What do you call a dorsal support on a seat?

Tags: word-request

[image: https://preview.redd.it/ze6lrbhmx2k31.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=cd76fca2403748fa296b2c34187d9151cba811a3]

What do you call a dorsal support perpendicular to a seat? I am not talking about the dorsal support found on a long couch seat, but any seat particularly those found in a bike. Is there a word for these dorsal support perpendicular to the seat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for a **backrest** like this:

[image]

(source: https://www.harley-davidson.com/us/en/shop/Comfort-Stitch-Adjustable-Rider-Backrest-Kit/p/52423-09A)